# Vue.js - Using Promises on Websocket?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket, promise

I'm facing an issue when using websocket with vue, becase I expect a variable to keep the last readystate.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCUmO.png)

In fisrt line, the readyState is 0, but in sequence readyState is 3. How can I get readyState equal 3?

```js
  const params = Object.entries({
  user: `${this.username}@${this.$props.uid}`,
  passwd: encodeURIComponent(this.passwd),
  cols: this.xterm.cols,
  rows: this.xterm.rows
})
  .map(([k, v]) => {
    return `${k}=${v}`;
  })
  .join("&");

this.ws = await new WebSocket(`ws://${location.host}/ws/ssh?${params}`);

// stateConection = true
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.log(this.ws);
```

Comment: The easiest way to use WebSocket is using module such as `vue-websocket` https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-websocket

Comment: `await` is used to *await* a promise being resolved. `new AnythingThatIsntAPromise` wont return a Promise you can *await* - having said that,, `this.ws` will be an instance of WebSocket, so while your code is adding a meaningless *await*, the code still would work as if the *await* were not present

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Promise` that resolves upon `open`, and rejects upon `error` or `close`.

```
const ws = new WebSocket(`ws://${location.host}/ws/ssh?${params}`);
const ready = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ws.onopen = resolve;
    ws.onerror = reject;
    ws.onclose = reject;
});
await ready;
```

This will await until the websocket is open, or throw an error if the websockets closes with or without an error.